# Display joomla module inside a component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Is it possible to write `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="" />`
inside a component? For example, to add this line to the COM_CONTENT or K2 default item.php or article.php templates in order to display a module as a part of my component and not seperated from it by the template I created?

I tried this one couple of times but never succeded, I don't know if it's just not possible or I'm doing something wrong, I'm not very strong with PHP, better with front-end.

Really hope its possible, will help me alot!

Thanks for your answers.

Shir

Comment: Im sorry, it deleted my code. im trying to write a Jdoc type module declaration inside a component, like this:
jdoc:include type="modules" name=""

Comment: No you can't do that (that happens a lot earlier). But what you can do is use the module api to get the module and convert it to a string, then echo it out.